# Why does the following shorthand not work in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, array-map

Here's a block of code that takes an array of strings and converts them into an integer.

To be more clear, it parses the numerical characters to integers.

```js
console.log(['1', '2', '0'].map((num) => Number.parseInt(num)))
```

The above works as expected. However, the following shorthand does not work.

```js
console.log(['1', '2', '0'].map(Number.parseInt))
```

You can run the code snippet and you will find that the first snippet logs the result `1`, `2` and `0` as expected. However, the latter logs `1`, `NaN` and `0`.

Is there somewhere I am going wrong here in using this shorthand?

Comment: tl;dr, the wrong param is parsed to parseInt

Comment: The first example *explicitly* provides one argument to `parseInt`, but the second example *implicitly* provides two.